# Perl file I/O issues: Script erasing all file contents instead of just removing numbers.

Tags: perl

I've been trying to get this Perl script to remove number lines in a file, and am having some issues. I am a Perl noob and am only using it for this one homework assignment. I've done a lot of research, though, and this code seems like it should work, but instead of removing the numbers from the text file containing

> 01 Now is
>
> 02 The time
>
> 03 To remove
>
> 04 Numbers

my script just erases the entire file contents. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my logic or syntax, or whatever it may be?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open my $in, '<', "rmv_num_lines.txt" or die "Can't read from file.\n"; # open for reading

@array = <in>; # fill array with contents of file

open my $out, '>', "rmv_num_lines.txt" or die "Can't write to file.\n"; # open for writing

while( <$in> ){
        foreach $item(@array){
                if($item =~ /\d/){ # if line contains a digit
                        $item =~ s/\d/\n/; # erase digit, I think?
}
}
        print $out $_;  # print edited array into file
}

close $out;
```

Comment: Were you able to read any lines with [at]array = <in> ? I think it needs to be [at]array = <$in> since you opened $in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(my $fh_in, '<', "rmv_num_lines.txt");
my $temp = ""; #Create temporarily Scalar Variable
while (<$fh_in>)
{
    $_=~s/^\d+ //;
    $temp .= $_; #Sequence storage in the temp variable
}
close($fh_in); #Close the file before Creating the same
open(my $fh_out, '>', "rmv_num_lines.txt");
print $fh_out $temp;
```

Comment: WOW! That did it! If you have time, could you explain what you did differently from me to make it work? Or better yet, what I was doing wrong? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Once you Opened file, couldn't able create again the same file or overwrite or rename... I should think may be.

Comment: Why did you move array from an array like the OP used? That was a needless change.

Answer (score 4):

- You used `@array = <in>;` instead of `@array = <$in>;`!
- When you actually tried to read the file using `while (<$in>)`, it had already been clobbered by `open '>'`.
- `s/\d/\n/` doesn't just remove a digit; it adds a newline in its place.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $qfn = 'rmv_num_lines.txt';

open my $in_fh, '<', $qfn
   or die "Can't open $qfn: $!\n";

my @lines = <$in_fh>;

open my $out_fh, '>', $qfn
   or die "Can't create $qfn: $!\n";

for my $line (@lines) {
    $line =~ s/^\d+ //;
    print $out_fh $line;
}
```

---

As a one-liner:

```
perl -i -pe's/^\d+ //' rmv_num_lines.txt
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I tried your recommendation. Here is what my code looks like: 


`#!/usr/bin/perl


open(my $fh_in, '<', "rmv_num_lines.txt");


open(my $fh_out, '>', "rmv_num_lines.txt");


while (<$fh_in>) {


   s/^\d+\s+//;
   
   print($fh_out $_);
}
`

Terribly sorry this isn't formatted nicely, I don't use the site a lot. Did I utilize your code correctly? Because it is still erasing all my file contents.

Comment: I didn't realize you were writing to the same file you were reading. Fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not supposed to create a new file, just edit the one I'm given.

Comment: `$line` and `@lines` are far more descriptive names than `$item` and `@array`.

Comment: Ok, noted. When you say the main loop, do you mean that I should replace my while loop with one of the ones you listed? Because if that's the case, I tried that and it is still erasing all content of the file. Maybe it's my system or something? I can't figure out why that wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Yes, `open '>'` erases the file, but then the print in the loop repopulates it from the array.

Comment: Ah! You used `@array = <in>;` instead of `@array = <$in>;`!